# How are correlation length and cluster size related in the 2D Ising model?

Tags: ising-model, correlation-functions

What is the relationship between correlation length and cluster size? Does the correlation length give the average cluster size, or is the cluster size something different?

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more on your question. In particular, the second question is not clear to me. Something different to what?

Comment: Can the cluster size distribution for a lattice at certain temperature have any relation with correlation length?

Comment: That explains (or rather repeats) question 1. Question 2 is unclear to me.

Comment: @myradio Your edits caused more harm than help.  There is only one question (which was more clear before the edit): Is (correlation length)=(cluster size): yes or no?

Comment: I agree that you stated the question in the body more clear. I wasn't even able to understand it. Nevertheless, I cannot understand the question that you put in the title. You rolled back a grammatical error that makes the question non-sense.

Comment: Sorry, I answer before your edit. Makes sense your edit in the body, I hope is what the OP meant because is an interpretation. My edits just corrected some format/grammar without making any change in meaning (even if it was necessary).

Comment: @myradio Ah, fair point - I have removed the "does" at the beginning, but overlooked the second "are".  Fixed.  BTW, if you don't understand the question, maybe it is a better idea not to edit the content -- your edit made it impossible to even guess what was meant (unlike the original).  In particular, there was no 2nd question.  --- BTW, you need to ping me with @[username], otherwise I won't see your comment.

Comment: @kamleswarchandrasekaran How do you *define* "cluster size"?  I mean, a cluster is not simply a circle.  It likely has holes and fuzzy edges, it might even be fractal, and so forth.